# How much is the lifetime of a Service Worker, can it be controlled?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I tried to googled and find an anwser but I didnt managed to find a clear answer.

Lets say I deployed a service worker that has a bug, syntax bug which causes my app to not run (and be able to re-register a fixed version of the service worker).

For how long will the buggy sw be on the user's browser?
Is it a way to define the life-time of a service worker? Lets say to be unregistered/killed by itself after some hours?

Answer (score 4):

Everything I know about the service worker lifecycle is at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle - pretty sure this covers your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Someone mentioned the lifetime is I think 1 hour... then it is redownloaded... but you can use cache header for it to be rechecked everyttime

Answer (score 2):

Lifetime of a service worker is usually defined as how long a service worker instance will be kept alive at runtime (think of service worker as a simple js script, once its lifetime ends the script exits and you lose all your local variables).

Lifetime of a service worker can be [pretty short](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#service-worker-lifetime):

> The lifetime of a service worker is tied to the execution lifetime of events and not references held by service worker clients to the ServiceWorker object.
>
> A user agent may terminate service workers at any time it:
>
> - Has no event to handle.
> - Detects abnormal operation: such as infinite loops and tasks exceeding imposed time limits (if any) while handling the events.

Lifetime is different from lifecycle - the latter specifies the different stages a service worker will go through **during its lifetime**.

What you are asking is more about lifecycle, because what you care is when the service worker will be upgraded (code re-downloaded, service worker instance re-created, activated, and started controlling your pages). Details on that can be found [here](https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/#updates):

> An update is triggered if any of the following happens:
>
> - A navigation to an in-scope page.
> - A functional events such as push and sync, unless there's been an update check within the previous 24 hours.
> - Calling .register() only if the service worker URL has changed. However, you should avoid changing the worker URL.

In order to control the update frequency, you can periodically register the service worker and [call the update method manually](https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/#manual-updates).